# write blob to a text file?

Tags: javascript, three.js, html5-canvas

i am able to see the text that has to be written to file in new window. Using following code.but i want save it to a text file locally.tried with `saveAs` and `msSaveBlob` it gives an error.

> window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, 'msSaveBlob_testFile.txt');
>
> var blob = new Blob([output]), {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
>   saveAs(blob, "thing.txt");

```
function exportGeometry ( ) {
    var output=[];
    output.push("//TLR:Format:Vishama Creations:v1.0\n//Pattern_no,Pattern_NumLines,FrstPointIndx,PointName,aX,aY,aZ,bX,bY,bZ,SecondPointIndex,PointName,aX,aY,aZ,bX,bY,bZ\nL\n");
    output.push(fpatternIndex);
    output.push(fpatternLineCount);
    output.push(fpatternPointCount);
    for(var b=0;b<fpatternLineCount;b++)
    {
        output.push(ffirstPtIndx[b]);
        output.push(fpatternPointName[ffirstPtIndx[b]]);
        output.push(fpatternPoint[ffirstPtIndx[b]].x/300);
        output.push(fpatternPoint[ffirstPtIndx[b]].y/300);
        output.push(fpatternPoint[ffirstPtIndx[b]].z/300);

        output.push(fsecondPtIndx[b]);
        output.push(fpatternPointName[fsecondPtIndx[b]]);
        output.push(fpatternPoint[fsecondPtIndx[b]].x/300);
        output.push(fpatternPoint[fsecondPtIndx[b]].y/300);
        output.push(fpatternPoint[fsecondPtIndx[b]].z/300);
    }
    output.push("\nL\n");
            output.push(bpatternIndex);
            output.push(bpatternLineCount);
            output.push(bpatternPointCount);
            for(var b=0;b<bpatternLineCount;b++)
            {
                output.push(bfirstPtIndx[b]);
                output.push(bpatternPointName[bfirstPtIndx[b]]);
                output.push(bpatternPoint[bfirstPtIndx[b]].x/300);
                output.push(bpatternPoint[bfirstPtIndx[b]].y/300);
                output.push(bpatternPoint[bfirstPtIndx[b]].z/300);

                output.push(bsecondPtIndx[b]);
                output.push(bpatternPointName[bsecondPtIndx[b]]);
                output.push(bpatternPoint[bsecondPtIndx[b]].x/300);
                output.push(bpatternPoint[bsecondPtIndx[b]].y/300);
                output.push(bpatternPoint[bsecondPtIndx[b]].z/300);
    }


    var blob = new Blob(([output]), {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});

    var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL( blob);
    window.open( objectURL, '_blank' );
    window.focus();

};
```

> tried like saveAs(blob ,test.txt) rises an error.. saveAs not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the `saveAs()` is not supported by any of the browsers currently.

you can just quickly check this by the following code

```
if (window.saveAs) {
    console.log("saveAs supported");
}else{
    console.log("saveAs not supported");
}
```

Now coming back to your problem,you have successfully created the text file that you are able to see in the new Window, you just have to create an anchor element(`<a></a>`) and simulate a user click to start the download in the browser.

This can be done by adding the following lines of code in in place of `window.open( objectURL, '_blank' ); window.focus();`

**Additional Code**

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.download = "test.txt";
a.href = url;
a.click();// you can use a.onclick(); if the former fails
```

Here is a

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shivasaxena/qnYk4/3/)

Answer (score -1):

I struggled with this issue but what worked for me is to force your html to only use supported browser versions - IE would drop to lower than supported for some stupid reason so I used...

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
```

...in the header of the HTML page and start your output variable (that you'll blob up later) outside your function but still inside your script tags, example:

```
<script src="FileSaver.js"></script>
<script>

var output; 

function exportGeometry ( ) {

    var output=''; ...
```

This is assuming you use the script FileSaver.js, if not you can learn about it at:
https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

hope this helps and I wish you the best of luck!

Comment: This answer is not very helpful without some commentary on what `filesaver.js` is, where you would get it, and why it is necessary.

Comment: My apologies I've added a link explaining what it does, demonstrations of use and downloads of the required files - I use it to convert a variable to a blob then to a file for download.